# Receiving Illegal start of expression error

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this error?
when i remove the () i have 100 errors...
cannot response on my own post need to wait 7hours ...

Im still getting errors, can someone maybe help me via teamvieuwer?

```
long TimeTNL = ()(Skills.getXPToNextLevel("Mining") * 3600000.0D / XPH);
                ^
```

1 error

---

```
this.runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
timeRan = this.runTime - this.startTime;
int XPH = (int)(this.gainedXP * 3600000.0D / timeRan);
long TimeTNL = ()(Skills.getXPToNextLevel("Mining") * 3600000.0D / XPH);
if (XPH > 0) {
  this.TNLhours = (TimeTNL / 3600000L);
  TimeTNL -= this.TNLhours * 3600000L;
  this.TNLminutes = (TimeTNL / 60000L);
  TimeTNL -= this.TNLminutes * 60000L;
  this.TNLseconds = (TimeTNL / 1000L);
  TimeTNL -= this.TNLseconds * 1000L;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript. And why not just removing the `()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `()` after the assignment operator in the variable declaration, they (parenthesis) are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is not Javascript, this is Java! Java to Javascript is like a high chair to electric chair!

Just remove the `()` - why are those in there? :)

Comment: Can you come on skype for a second and add me?

Comment: Or can you help me via teamvieuwer? :)

Comment: I would rather not, see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user : `It could hide information from the community: useful information transmitted privately is unavailable to other readers, subverting the core purpose of the site.` - if you have any further issues I will be happy to help if you post extra information in this question, or ask another one